# How would I navigate to a new route inside a list widget? (Line 41: context,) is where the issue occurs

Tags: flutter, dart

```dart
 import 'dart:js';
    
    import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:english_words/english_words.dart';
    
    void main() => runApp(const MyApp());
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return const MaterialApp(
          title: _title,
          home: MyStatefulWidget(),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
      const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
    }
    
    class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
      int _selectedIndex = 0;
      static const TextStyle optionStyle =
          TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
      // ignore: prefer_final_fields
      static List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
        Container(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            child: const Text('Open route'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(

**This is where the error occurs: I am unsure of how to access or use context within list widgets**    

                context, // ********THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS******
   
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SecondRoute()),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          'Index 1: Business',
          style: optionStyle,
        ),
        Text(
          'Index 2: School',
          style: optionStyle,
        ),
      ];
    
      void _onItemTapped(int index) {
        setState(() {
          _selectedIndex = index;
        });
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('OBTAIN'),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
          ),
          drawer: Drawer(
            // Add a ListView to the drawer. This ensures the user can scroll
            // through the options in the drawer if there isn't enough vertical
            // space to fit everything.
            child: ListView(
              // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              children: [
                const DrawerHeader(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                  child: Text('Drawer Header'),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  title: const Text('Item 1'),
                  onTap: () {
                    // Update the state of the app
                    // ...
                    // Then close the drawer
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                ),
                ListTile(
                  title: const Text('Item 2'),
                  onTap: () {
                    // Update the state of the app
                    // ...
                    // Then close the drawer
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                label: 'Home',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.business),
                label: 'Business',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.school),
                label: 'School',
              ),
            ],
            currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
            selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
            onTap: _onItemTapped,
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
      const SecondRoute({super.key});
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Second Route'),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: const Text('Go back!'),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

How would I navigate to a new route inside a list widget? (Line 41: context,) is where the issue occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you are trying to get context direct under state class. There is trick can be done using `late` keyword or do inside `initState`. (You can't use static)

Also avoid using context like this when ever possible.

> "It breaks the context chain, which means you're violating the build system's contract." - And this variable wont be responde to update untill you reintalize this variable inisde setState.

```dart
  late List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Container(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: const Text('Open route'),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SecondRoute()),
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 1: Business',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 2: School',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
  ];
```

Comment: I am doing some research on this, I appreciate it! I used the keyword but I cannot seem to get it to work with "context" even when using late instead of static

Comment: It wont work with static, but what is the reason behind using static

Comment: none, i used the late keyword but i still cannot seem to fix the bug that occurs with "context"

Comment: did you try with removing `static` and are you using null safety? And also remove the js import from 1st line.

Comment: the js import was the issue, I completely forgot. Thank you!